# Jquery recursively compare two elements on their html and attributes

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion, compare, updates

I'm trying to make an intelligent way to copy HTML from one element to another.

Let's say I have the below.  I want to copy the structure from ".from" to ".to".  I can copy wholesale with .html() but this is slow for a large tree, and causes a flicker as the browser redraws.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way I could recursively dig through each element's tree and compare element by element.  So if only one element's HTML or attributes have changed, I only need to change that one element - everything else stays the same.

In the example below, ".a" would have unchanged attributes, but changed HTML. ".b" would need to dig into its children and change the attributes and HTML of ".x".  ".e" would have to be created in the target element.

Does anyone know of an intelligent way to do this?

```
<ul class="to">
    <li class="a">test1</li>
    <li class="b">
         <div class="x">test2</div>
    </li>
    <li>test3</li>
    <li class="c">test4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="from">
    <li class="a">test5</li>
    <li class="b">
         <div class="y">test6</div>
    </li>
    <li class="c">test7</li>
    <li class="d">test4</li>
    <li class="e">test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pfft, I would consider whether you actually gain anything doing this. By the time you've traversed a potentially large tree and compared every attribute, is it actually more efficient?

Comment: I agree it seems slightly odd but a main reason is to avoid flashes as the element redraws - hence wanting to do it like this.

Comment: If you're modifying alot of elements, then I'm not sure if that will make for *less* visual glitches. If you `.clone()` the element, does that cause a flicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at my solution: http://javascripts.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javascripts/javascripts/js.prototype-extensions/js/extensions/element.js?view=markup - starting from comment `Smooth update of DOM subtree`, this code may be easily adopted to jQuery.

In short words, function `updateSmoothly` compares two DOM subtrees (source and destination) node by node, trying to preserve existing nodes and make as minimal changes in source subtree as possible. In your example it will change text values, add/remove CSS classes of already existing text/element nodes, and append only one `LI` to list.

This solution is working in production environment, updating tables with 1300+ rows fast enough even in IE8.

P.S. Similar answer to another question: [Updating gigantic HTML table with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013900/updating-gigantic-html-table-with-ajax/13248382#13248382)