# Updating gigantic HTML table with ajax

Tags: ajax, optimization, prototypejs, updates

Have a table with 2000+ rows and I need to have a single div on each row updated periodically.  I hoped to update every 10 seconds, but the page becomes quite sluggish.

The server has 32gb RAM and my laptop has 8gb RAM, both have at least two quad cores.

Here's the div & update call:

```
<div id='div_$id' name='div_$id'></div>

<script language='javascript'>
    new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('div_$id', 'upd.php',{ 
       method: 'post', 
       frequency: 10, 
       decay: 1, 
       parameters: {id:'$id'}}
    );
</script>
```

I'm using the latest version of Prototype (1.7.0.0).   Is there a faster, better way of doing this, or am I going to be forced to roll back the frequency to a minute or more?

Comment: 2000+ rows ? My 2 cents, this is an antipattern... can't use pagination ?

Comment: Negative on pagination.  Client needs it all on one page.

Comment: On the backend, create table data as an XML / JSON file whenever an update is made. Then do your check every ten seconds if the file has been updated. Only load the XML/JSON data if it is newer than current data.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  There are input elements on each row. The "div_$id" shows last updated by.   Idea is to prevent two people from working on the same row simultaneously.  If I reload the table when user 1 makes an update and user 2 has unsaved data..  I'm saving data onBlur, so maybe that is a mute point.

Comment: If you can capture when a user begins an edit ("onClick" of edit element) you can lock the file for updating ( with a db timestamp entry ) until they finish updating...or 20 seconds pass. ?

Comment: I've personally never used websockets, but they seem perfect for your 'row locking' problem. On focus, message the sever that you've got dibs, server messages other clients to lock their UI. That is, if I fully understand their use. Maybe someone else can chime in or you can do some googling to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: I agree with @dontGoPlastic. You can also just use a simple check requests for what cells are locked that are more frequent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [1500 row table with each row containing a form - Ajax or something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974317/1500-row-table-with-each-row-containing-a-form-ajax-or-something-else)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Do not use bulk update. Retrieve updated HTML content, and compare two DOM subtrees: current and updated. Do as small changes as possible and only when differences found - text node changed, element inserted/removed. Look at code http://javascripts.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javascripts/javascripts/js.prototype-extensions/js/extensions/element.js?view=markup - function updateSmoothly at the end of file. Each element will have new method `Element#updateSmoothly(content)`, then you can pass additional `insertion` option to updater:

   ```
   new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('div_$id', 'upd.php', { 
     method: 'post', 
     frequency: 10, 
     decay: 1, 
     parameters: {id:'$id'},
     insertion: function(receiver, responseText) {
       receiver.updateSmoothly(responseText);
     }
   });
   ```

   This code worked in IE8 updating table with ~1300 rows, and UI was still more or less responsive (CPU Core 2 Duo, RAM 3Gb, OS Vista Home).
2. Major optimization is possible with use of something similar to endless scroll technique. UI user anyway *can't see all 2000+ rows simultaneously* on the screen - the biggest part of the table is off the screen. Why you need to download and update something what isn't even visible? Why you need to have in DOM something invisible? Just track which part of the table is currently visible and request from server updates for this only part. Delete rows when they going off the screen and load new rows when they should become visible.

Comment: Went with a solution similar to the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974317/1500-row-table-with-each-row-containing-a-form-ajax-or-something-else